# Select records with substr

Tags: sqlite, substr

In my table I have a column production with strings like 101014, 101015. I want to select all the records which end with 15. I asked with:

```
SELECT * FROM boxes where substr('production',5,2) = 15
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM boxes where substr('production',5) = 15
```

and nothing is returned..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM boxes where production like '%15'
```

Or if you want `substr`, instead of:

```
SELECT * FROM boxes where substr('production',5) = 15
```

try:

```
SELECT * FROM boxes where substr(production,5) = '15'
```

Comment: this `SELECT * FROM boxes where substr('production',5) = '15'` doesn't work either

Comment: Probably `production` is treated as string, delete '`' and try.